# What is causing this broken animation/transition in a Vue.js component in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, vue.js, css-transitions, requestanimationframe

```js
const NotificationBar = {
  name: 'notification-bar',

  template: `
    <div
      :class="{
        'notification-bar': true,
        'notification-bar--error': isError,
        'notification-bar--warning': isWarning,
        'notification-bar--info': isInfo,
        'notification-bar--visible': isVisible,
      }"

      @click="dismiss"
      @transitionend="transitionEnd($event)">
      {{ message }}
    </div>
  `,

  props: {
    message: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },

    type: {
      type: String,
      required: true,

      validator(value) {
        const valid = ['error', 'warning', 'info'];
        return valid.includes(value);
      },
    },

    dismissable: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },

    timeout: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
  },

  data() {
    return {
      isVisible: false,
    };
  },

  computed: {
    isError() {
      return this.type === 'error';
    },

    isWarning() {
      return this.type === 'warning';
    },

    isInfo() {
      return this.type === 'info';
    },
  },

  methods: {
    clear() {
      const event = 'cleared';
      let done;

      if (this.isVisible) {
        this.$once('transitionend', () => {
          done = true;
          this.$emit(event, done);
        });
        this.isVisible = false;
      } else {
        done = false;
        this.$emit(event, done);
      }
    },

    dismiss() {
      const event = 'dismissed';
      let done;

      if (this.dismissable) {
        done = true;
        this.$emit(event, done);
        this.clear();
      } else {
        done = false;
        this.$emit(event, done);
      }
    },

    show() {
      if (!this.isVisible) {
        this.isVisible = true;
        this.$emit('show', this.clear);

        if (this.timeout) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.$emit('timeout');
            this.clear();
          }, this.timeout);
        }
      }
    },

    transitionEnd(event) {
      this.$emit('transitionend', event);
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(this.show);
  },
};

const NotificationCenter = {
  name: 'notification-center',

  components: {
    NotificationBar,
  },

  template: `
    <div>
      <notification-bar
        v-for="notification in active"

        :message="notification.message"
        :type="notification.type"
        :dismissable="notification.dismissable"
        :timeout="notification.timeout"

        @cleared="clear">
      </notification-bar>
    </div>
  `,

  props: {
    queue: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
  },

  data() {
    return {
      active: [],
    };
  },

  computed: {
    hasActiveNotification() {
      return this.active.length > 0;
    },

    hasQueuedNotification() {
      return this.queue.length > 0;
    },
  },

  watch: {
    queue() {
      if (this.hasQueuedNotification && !this.hasActiveNotification) {
        this.setNextActive();
      }
    },
  },

  methods: {
    setNextActive() {
      this.setActive(this.queue.shift());
    },

    setActive(notification) {
      this.active.push(notification);
    },

    removeActive() {
      this.active.pop();
    },

    clear() {
      this.active.pop();

      if (this.hasQueuedNotification) {
        this.$nextTick(this.setNextActive);
      }
    },
  },
};

window.vm = new Vue({
  components: {
    NotificationCenter,
  },

  el: '#app',

  template: `
    <div>
      <notification-center
        :queue="notifications">
      </notification-center>

      <label>
        <strong>Type</strong> <br>
        Error <input v-model="type" type="radio" name="type" value="error"> <br>
        Warning <input v-model="type" type="radio" name="type" value="warning"> <br>
        Info <input v-model="type" type="radio" name="type" value="info"> <br>
      </label>

      <label>
        <strong>Message</strong>
        <input v-model="message" type="text">
      </label>

      <label>
        <strong>Dismissable</strong>
        <input v-model="dismissable" type="checkbox">
      </label>

      <label>
        <strong>Timeout</strong>
        <input v-model="timeout" type="number" step="100" min="0">
      </label>

      <button @click="generateNotification">Generate notification</button>
    </div>
  `,

  data: {
    notifications: [],
    
    type: null,
    message: null,
    dismissable: null,
    timeout: null,
  },
  
  methods: {
    generateNotification() {
      const {
        type,
        message,
        dismissable,
        timeout,
      } = this;
      
      this.notifications.push({
        type,
        message,
        dismissable,
        timeout,
      });
      
      this.type = this.message = this.dismissable = this.timeout = null;
    },
  },
});
```

```css
.notification-bar {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: -3.2rem;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3.2rem;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Avenir Next', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 3.2rem;
  text-align: center;
  transition: top 266ms ease;
}
.notification-bar--error {
  background-color: #f02a4d;
}
.notification-bar--warning {
  background-color: #ffc107;
}
.notification-bar--info {
  background-color: #2196f3;
}
.notification-bar--visible {
  top: 0;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin: 2rem 0;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}
label:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
      html {
        font-size: 62.5%;
      }
      
      body {
        font-family: sans-serif;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

## Steps to reproduce problem

1. Run above snippet in Chrome.
2. Generate a notification. (Set **type** to anything, set **message** to anything, set **dismissable**, click **Generate notification**)
3. Observe notification bar

## Expected behaviour

Notification bar smoothly animates into the visible viewport. You can observe this by doing the steps above in Firefox.

**Here is a GIF demonstrating the correct behaviour in Chrome.** Upon clicking **Generate notification** you can see the bar smoothly transitioning in.

[image: GIF of expected behaviour]

**Here is the screenshot of the timeline when Chrome is behaving correctly:**

[image: Timeline of expected behaviour]

**Here is the call tree when Chrome is behaving correctly:**

[image: Call tree of expected behaviour]

## Actual behaviour

Notification bar does not smoothly animate into the visible viewport the majority of the time. Capturing a timeline in Chrome Devtools shows no animation running when notification bar is being shown. Animations always run correctly when bar is animating off screen. Animation always runs correctly in Firefox.

**Here is a GIF demonstrating the incorrect behaviour in Chrome.** Upon clicking **Generate notification** you can see the bar suddenly appearing.

[image: GIF of incorrect behaviour]

**Here is the screenshot of the timeline when Chrome is not behaving correctly:**

[image: Timeline of incorrect behaviour]

**Here is the call tree when Chrome is not behaving correct:**

[image: Call tree of incorrect behaviour]

## Additional information

**Outline of what code is doing**:

1. `NotificationCenter` takes in a `queue` prop. This is an array of objects with the array representing a queue of notifications and an object representing a single notification.
2. Once the `queue` changes, a watcher runs checking if there are notifications in the queue and if there isn't an active notification. If this is the case, the next notification is set as the active notification.
3. `NotificationCenter`'s template has a directive looping over items in `active` and renders a `NotificationBar`. In the previous step, a new active notification was set thus a new notification bar will be created and mounted to the DOM.
4. Once the `NotificationBar` is mounted on the DOM, its `show` method is run inside of `window.requestAnimationFrame`.

Comment: I get smooth animation on a Mac running Chrome v 56.0.2924.87

Comment: @RoyJ: do you get it consistently?

Comment: Yes, I've run the snippet multiple times (full screen). Every time, the banner slides in smoothly from the top.

Comment: @RoyJ: thanks for confirming that. I've narrowed the problem down further. The notification bar not smoothly animating in Chrome only happens when sending the first notification after a page load. Subsequent notifications animate smoothly. Would you be able to say this is the case for you as well?

Comment: It runs the same the first time as subsequent times for me.

Comment: @RoyJ: interesting that you cannot reproduce. Will need to see if I can reproduce elsewhere. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some discussion with [LinusBorg](https://forum.vuejs.org/users/LinusBorg), a contributor to Vue, on the [Vue forum](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/what-is-causing-this-broken-animation-transition-in-a-vue-js-component-in-chrome/7742/) we had a possible cause for this problem:

> [...] the issue is likely that Vue patches the DOM asynchronously, so when `mounted()` is called, the elements of the components exist, but they are not guranteed to be in the DOM.
>
> And so now, depending on how different browsers handle the priorities of normal tasks, microtasks and animationFrames, it may simply be the case that in Chrome, the element is not in the DOM yet, when you change the class through `show()`
>
> In that case, the animation effect would not appear, naturally.
>
> I suggest to try `this.$nextTick()` instead (which guarantees that the element is already in the DOM), or simply use the tools Vue gives you for this, namely the `<transition>` component.

– LinusBorg, https://forum.vuejs.org/t/what-is-causing-this-broken-animation-transition-in-a-vue-js-component-in-chrome/7742/7

Attempts to use `this.$nextTick` were made initially but failed in both Firefox and Chrome.

Eventually I was able to implement this whole thing using the `<transition>` component.

```js
const NotificationBar = {
  name: 'notification-bar',
  
  template: `
    <transition
      name="visible"
      mode="out-in"

      @after-enter="show">
      <div
        :class="{
          'notification-bar': true,
          'notification-bar--error': isError,
          'notification-bar--warning': isWarning,
          'notification-bar--info': isInfo,
          'notification-bar--visible': isVisible,
        }"

        :key="id"

        @click="dismiss">
        {{ message }}
      </div>
    </transition>
  `,

  props: {
    message: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },

    type: {
      type: String,
      required: true,

      validator(value) {
        const valid = ['error', 'warning', 'info'];
        return valid.includes(value);
      },
    },

    id: {
      type: [Number, String],
      required: true,
    },

    dismissable: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },

    timeout: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
  },

  data() {
    return {
      isVisible: false,
    };
  },

  computed: {
    isError() {
      return this.type === 'error';
    },

    isWarning() {
      return this.type === 'warning';
    },

    isInfo() {
      return this.type === 'info';
    },
  },

  methods: {
    clear() {
      const event = 'clear';
      let done;

      if (this.isVisible) {
        done = true;
        this.$emit(event, done);
        this.isVisible = false;
      } else {
        done = false;
        this.$emit(event, done);
      }
    },

    dismiss() {
      const event = 'dismissed';
      let done;

      if (this.dismissable) {
        done = true;
        this.$emit(event, done);
        this.clear();
      } else {
        done = false;
        this.$emit(event, done);
      }
    },

    show() {
      if (!this.isVisible) {
        this.isVisible = true;
        this.$emit('show', this.clear);

        if (this.timeout) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.$emit('timeout');
            this.clear();
          }, this.timeout);
        }
      }
    },
  },
};

const NotificationCenter = {
  name: 'notification-center',
  
  template: `
    <div>
      <notification-bar
        v-if="hasQueuedNotification"

        :message="activeNotification.message"
        :type="activeNotification.type"
        :dismissable="activeNotification.dismissable"
        :timeout="activeNotification.timeout"
        :id="activeNotification.id"

        @clear="clear">
      </notification-bar>
    </div>
  `,

  components: {
    NotificationBar,
  },

  props: {
    queue: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
  },

  computed: {
    hasQueuedNotification() {
      return this.queue.length > 0;
    },

    activeNotification() {
      return this.queue[0];
    },
  },

  methods: {
    clear() {
      this.queue.shift();
    },
  },
};

window.vm = new Vue({
  components: {
    NotificationCenter,
  },

  el: '#app',

  template: `
    <div>
      <notification-center
        :queue="notifications">
      </notification-center>

      <label>
        <strong>Type</strong> <br>
        Error <input v-model="type" type="radio" name="type" value="error"> <br>
        Warning <input v-model="type" type="radio" name="type" value="warning"> <br>
        Info <input v-model="type" type="radio" name="type" value="info"> <br>
      </label>

      <label>
        <strong>Message</strong>
        <input v-model="message" type="text">
      </label>

      <label>
        <strong>Dismissable</strong>
        <input v-model="dismissable" type="checkbox">
      </label>

      <label>
        <strong>Timeout</strong>
        <input v-model="timeout" type="number" step="100" min="0">
      </label>

      <button @click="generateNotification">Generate notification</button>
    </div>
  `,

  data: {
    notifications: [],

    type: null,
    message: null,
    dismissable: null,
    timeout: null,

    dismissIndex: null,
    dismissMessage: null,
  },

  methods: {
    generateNotification() {
      const {
        type,
        message,
        dismissable,
        timeout,
      } = this;

      const id = Date.now();

      this.notifications.push({
        type,
        message,
        dismissable,
        timeout,
        id,
      });

      this.type = this.message = this.dismissable = this.timeout = null;
    },
  },
});
```

```css
.notification-bar {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3.2rem;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Avenir Next', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 3.2rem;
  text-align: center;
}
.notification-bar--error {
  background-color: #f02a4d;
}
.notification-bar--warning {
  background-color: #ffc107;
}
.notification-bar--info {
  background-color: #2196f3;
}
.notification-bar.visible-enter, .notification-bar.visible-leave-to {
  top: -3.2rem;
}
.notification-bar.visible-enter-to, .notification-bar.visible-leave {
  top: 0;
}
.notification-bar.visible-enter-active, .notification-bar.visible-leave-active {
  transition: top 266ms ease;
}

/* ================================================================== */
/*                                                                    */
/* ================================================================== */
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin: 2rem 0;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

label:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with this line:

```
this.type = this.message = this.dismissable = this.timeout = null;
```

If you remove this it works fine. as when this gets executed props becomes NULL and you have validation that props should not be null.

```js
const NotificationBar = {
  name: 'notification-bar',

  template: `
    <div
      :class="{
        'notification-bar': true,
        'notification-bar--error': isError,
        'notification-bar--warning': isWarning,
        'notification-bar--info': isInfo,
        'notification-bar--visible': isVisible,
      }"

      @click="dismiss"
      @transitionend="transitionEnd($event)">
      {{ message }}
    </div>
  `,

  props: {
    message: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },

    type: {
      type: String,
      required: true,

      validator(value) {
        const valid = ['error', 'warning', 'info'];
        return valid.includes(value);
      },
    },

    dismissable: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },

    timeout: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
  },

  data() {
    return {
      isVisible: false,
    };
  },

  computed: {
    isError() {
      return this.type === 'error';
    },

    isWarning() {
      return this.type === 'warning';
    },

    isInfo() {
      return this.type === 'info';
    },
  },

  methods: {
    clear() {
      const event = 'cleared';
      let done;

      if (this.isVisible) {
        this.$once('transitionend', () => {
          done = true;
          this.$emit(event, done);
        });
        this.isVisible = false;
      } else {
        done = false;
        this.$emit(event, done);
      }
    },

    dismiss() {
      const event = 'dismissed';
      let done;

      if (this.dismissable) {
        done = true;
        this.$emit(event, done);
        this.clear();
      } else {
        done = false;
        this.$emit(event, done);
      }
    },

    show() {
      if (!this.isVisible) {
        this.isVisible = true;
        this.$emit('show', this.clear);

        if (this.timeout) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.$emit('timeout');
            this.clear();
          }, this.timeout);
        }
      }
    },

    transitionEnd(event) {
      this.$emit('transitionend', event);
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(this.show);
  },
};

const NotificationCenter = {
  name: 'notification-center',

  components: {
    NotificationBar,
  },

  template: `
    <div>
      <notification-bar
        v-for="notification in active"

        :message="notification.message"
        :type="notification.type"
        :dismissable="notification.dismissable"
        :timeout="notification.timeout"

        @cleared="clear">
      </notification-bar>
    </div>
  `,

  props: {
    queue: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
  },

  data() {
    return {
      active: [],
    };
  },

  computed: {
    hasActiveNotification() {
      return this.active.length > 0;
    },

    hasQueuedNotification() {
      return this.queue.length > 0;
    },
  },

  watch: {
    queue() {
      if (this.hasQueuedNotification && !this.hasActiveNotification) {
        this.setNextActive();
      }
    },
  },

  methods: {
    setNextActive() {
      this.setActive(this.queue.shift());
    },

    setActive(notification) {
      this.active.push(notification);
    },

    removeActive() {
      this.active.pop();
    },

    clear() {
      this.active.pop();

      if (this.hasQueuedNotification) {
        this.$nextTick(this.setNextActive);
      }
    },
  },
};

window.vm = new Vue({
  components: {
    NotificationCenter,
  },

  el: '#app',

  template: `
    <div>
      <notification-center
        :queue="notifications">
      </notification-center>

      <label>
        <strong>Type</strong> <br>
        Error <input v-model="type" type="radio" name="type" value="error"> <br>
        Warning <input v-model="type" type="radio" name="type" value="warning"> <br>
        Info <input v-model="type" type="radio" name="type" value="info"> <br>
      </label>

      <label>
        <strong>Message</strong>
        <input v-model="message" type="text">
      </label>

      <label>
        <strong>Dismissable</strong>
        <input v-model="dismissable" type="checkbox">
      </label>

      <label>
        <strong>Timeout</strong>
        <input v-model="timeout" type="number" step="100" min="0">
      </label>

      <button @click="generateNotification">Generate notification</button>
    </div>
  `,

  data: {
    notifications: [],
    
    type: null,
    message: null,
    dismissable: null,
    timeout: null,
  },
  
  methods: {
    generateNotification() {
      const {
        type,
        message,
        dismissable,
        timeout,
      } = this;
      
      this.notifications.push({
        type,
        message,
        dismissable,
        timeout,
      });
      
      //this.type = this.message = this.dismissable = this.timeout = null;
    },
  },
});
```

```css
.notification-bar {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: -3.2rem;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3.2rem;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Avenir Next', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 3.2rem;
  text-align: center;
  transition: top 266ms ease;
}
.notification-bar--error {
  background-color: #f02a4d;
}
.notification-bar--warning {
  background-color: #ffc107;
}
.notification-bar--info {
  background-color: #2196f3;
}
.notification-bar--visible {
  top: 0;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin: 2rem 0;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}
label:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
      html {
        font-size: 62.5%;
      }
      
      body {
        font-family: sans-serif;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Edit

You have to put some validation in `setActive` function, as if you push empty item in active, some validations you have are failing.

```
  setActive(notification) {
    if(notification.message){
    this.active.push(notification);
    }
  },
```

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zrLLfftg/).

Comment: The line you are pointing only clears the input fields and the checkbox. The data from these inputs have already been pushed into the `notifications` property on the ViewModel and passed down to the `NotificationCenter` component which passes it down to the `NotificationBar` component. It does not affect `NotificationBar`'s prop validation or the actual problem described in the question.

Comment: @wing I get this error with that line: `Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "message". Expected String, got Null. 
(found in component <notification-bar>)`, without this line working fine. check updated answer.

Comment: Did you give a message to the notification in the first place? I don't intend to add protections for the developer not sending a message in the notification – that's why there's already prop validation that checks the message is a string and throws if it isn't. Regardless of the problem you are facing, it is unrelated to what I'm facing – which is a broken animation/transition in Chrome when the notification bar is being made visible.

Comment: @wing Than I will say it is working for me in Mac Chrome version  56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)

Comment: okai, thanks for your time, really confused about this seemingly phantom bug – I think I might have to make a GIF of it happening in case people are actually seeing the bug but thinking it's normal behaviour.

Comment: I've added GIFs showing the correct and incorrect behaviours, the differences are subtle but noticeable. You might want to compare them to what you saw when you attempted to reproduce my problem.